# What are the 5 music tracks that play for each of the World of Light shops?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate, game-music-identification

When you enter the shop, the game doesn't tell you what track is playing. All have somewhat distinct sounding tracks but I can't remember or match what song is playing in each of the shops.

What are the 5 music tracks that play for each of the World of Light shops?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The songs are are follows:

**Timmy and Tommy's shop**: Town Hall and Tom Nook's Store - Animal Crossing: Wild World *(Animal Crossing)*

**Beedle's shop**: Village of the Blue Maiden *(Zelda)*

**Funky Kong's shop**: Funky's Fugue *(Donkey Kong)*

**Anna's shop**: Conquest (Ablaze) *(Fire Emblem)*

**Sheldon's shop**: Kraken Up *(Splatoon)*

Source: I went through all the songs in the in-game song list manually until I found the matching songs. :P

Comment: And here I thought someone was just going to use something like Shazam on them. +1 for maximum effort!!